# Capistrano 3: Get server info from role

Tags: ruby, rake, capistrano, capistrano3

Is it possible to access the `hostname` and `user` of a role without using `on`, so I don't have to nest the task below so ugly?

```
task :foo do
    on roles(:web) do |host|
        run_locally do
            execute :rsync, '-avzr', "/foobar", "#{host.user}@#{host.hostname}:/foobar"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried simply calling `roles(:web).each |host|`?

Comment: I'm new to Ruby, could you give me an example?

Comment: `roles(:web).each do |host| exectue :rsync...`

Answer (score 5):

Solved using Uri Agassi suggestion to use `each`:

```
task :foo do
    run_locally do
        roles(:web).each do |host|
            execute :rsync, '-avzr', "/foobar", "#{host.user}@#{host.hostname}:/foobar"
        end
    end
end
```